# Populating custom array property in XAML

Tags: wpf, arrays, xaml

I am trying to populate a custom string array in XAML, but am receiving an error. I subclassed a ComboBox and added a string [] that I want to fill with custom values:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public string[] MyProperty { get { return (string[])GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); } set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string[]), typeof(MyComboBox));
}
```

My XAML is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="Samples.CustomArrayProperty"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Samples"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="CustomArrayProperty" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyComboBox Height="20">
            <local:MyComboBox.MyProperty>
                <sys:String>Monday</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Wednesday</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Friday</sys:String>
            </local:MyComboBox.MyProperty>
        </local:MyComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run this, I get the error: "'Monday' is not a valid value for property 'MyProperty'.".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You can create arrays in XAML using [x:Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340.aspx), you still need to use it as a resource like Liz's answer.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="sys:String" x:Key="days">
        <sys:String>Monday</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Wednesday</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Friday</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<local:MyComboBox Height="23" MyProperty="{StaticResource days}" />
```

Comment: So if I have a property on a UIElement that's an array Type (string[] for example), I have to set the value of the array directly? I was hoping there was a way to populate the array property in-line.

Comment: You can try putting x:array inline, for me it compiles and works but often during editing you get errors I'm not sure if it is supported and the behaviour did change between v3.5 and 4.0. If you need to do this frequently you could write a markup extension that splits a delimited string this could be one line of XAML then.

Comment: Do you mean <local:MyComboBox Height="20"> local:MyComboBox.MyProperty> <x:Array Type="sys:String"> ... values here ... ? That doesn't compile for me because it thinks I'm trying to add a string[] as a single element to a string[].

Comment: Yes. I don't think it is supported and wouldn't recommend using it `<local:MyComboBox.MyProperty><x:Array Type="sys:String" ><sys:String>Monday</sys:String><sys:String>Wednesday</sys:String><sys:String>Friday</sys:String></x:Array></local:MyComboBox.MyProperty>` does compile for me, you could try rebuilding solution beforehand. It seems to mess up Intellisense too so I'd just stick to using a resource.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any other reason you are subclassing the ComboBox beyond what you are doing here?

Because if the idea is to just provide a list of strings to the combobox then take a look at ["Add collection or array to wpf resource dictionary"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478738/add-collection-or-array-to-wpf-resource-dictionary)

As much as possible it would be better to let the combobox take care of itself - by using the ItemsSource property.  So what we are doing in the linked example is providing a 'resource' containing your list of strings, and then passing this resource to the ItemsSource as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource stringList}" />
```

Define a type like this:

```
public class StringList : List<string> { }
```

And then create a static resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringList x:Key="stringList">
        <sys:String>Monday</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Wednesday</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Friday</sys:String>
    </local:StringList >
</Window.Resources>
```

I hope that helps.

Edit: You could also change your DependencyProperty to use StringList instead of String[], then your dependency property will work as well.

```
<local:MyComboBox MyProperty="{StaticResource stringList}" Height="23" />
```

And then the dependencyProperty:

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty",typeof(StringList),typeof(MyComboBox),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, listChangedCallBack));

   static void listChangedCallBack(DependencyObject property, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
       ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)property;
       combo.ItemsSource= (IEnumerable)args.NewValue;
    }
```

Then this would effectively do the same thing as binding directly to the ItemsSource.  But the main thing if I understand you correctly, is just to get the Dependency property to work.

Comment: Thank you, but I was just using a ComboBox to try to simplify the problem. I inherited a custom control that has an Enumerable<string> property that's being populated in code, and I wanted to make it as XAML-friendly as possible without changing the object's definition.

Comment: ok, so if you change your Dependency property to use a List<String> instead of a String[] wouldn't that help you?  When I did that I had no issues setting the property 'MyProperty="{StaticResource stringList}"'

Comment: Yes, when I do that in a sample project it works, but it requires me to change my business object's definition and I'm not sure who's toes I'll be stepping on when I do that (unfortunately, the class appears to be poorly tested - I'll see this as an opportunity to write some more).

Comment: This answer worked for me but what If I want several controls each with different inputs. Should I create a resource for each control. I am finding that not user friendly. Is there a way that I can move the resources to be part of the control lines in the xaml?

Answer (score 1):

And, an extra example with `enum`:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public enum OrganizationType
    {
        Office365,
        OnPremisses
    }
}

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"

<x:Array Type="local:OrganizationType" x:Key="OrganizationTypeArray">
    <local:OrganizationType>Office365</local:OrganizationType>
    <local:OrganizationType>OnPremisses</local:OrganizationType>
</x:Array>
```